# Unhandlel promise rejection warning

Tags: javascript, typescript, unhandled

I'm using Promise.reject

I've got this warning: Unhandled promise rejection warning: version 1.1 is not released

how can I solve this warning ?

Thanks for your help

```
public async retrieveVersionFromJira(versionName: string): Promise<ReleaseVersion> {
        const searchVersionsUri = config.jiraApiUri + 'versions';
        const jsonResp = await this.jiraClient.get(searchVersionsUri);
        const version: any = jsonResp.find(version => {
            if (version.name == versionName) {
                if (version.released == true) {
                    return Promise.reject("version " + versionName + " is not released");
                }
            }
        });
        if (!version) {
            return Promise.reject("missing version " + versionName + " on jira");
        }
        return new ReleaseVersion(version.id, version.name, version.released);
    }
```

Comment: When you call your function you need to use a `try/catch` block if using `async/await` or a `.catch()` handler if using the Promise directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you call your function you need to use a try/catch block if using async/await or a .catch() handler if using the Promise directly:

```
try {
  const answr = await retrieveVersionFromJira('1.1');
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}

// alternatively
retrieveVersionFromJira('1.1').catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you call this function, you don't either have a `.catch` in the promise chain, or `try / catch` around `await retrieveVersionFromJira(...)` in async context.

That is, the promise gets rejected, but there's no code to handle the rejection, your code ignores it and proceeds. The runtime warns you about that.